# Electron: Sending Message from main.js to index.js

Tags: javascript, electron

Before i go on, i am new to electron and have just started using it yesterday so please elaborate your answers.

So I am creating a notepad application. I want to send a message when a submenu is clicked. This submenu and the BrowserWindow is in the `main.js` file. Whenever i click the submenu it should send a message which is then recieved by a script named index.js. (this script is included in my `index.html` which is the file loaded by the window).

This is what i tried to do:

```js
// main.js submenu
{
    'label': 'Open',
     click() {
         dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openfile']}).then(result => {
             win.webContents.send('open', result.filePaths[0])
        })
    }
}
```

```js
// index.js
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.on('open', (event, file) => {
    console.print(file)
    console.log('Recieved')
})
```

However this does not seem to work.

Comment: I would suggest you take an hour and read up on `ipc messaging`  – there are lots of articles out there: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Electron+ipc+messaging&t=ffsb&ia=web

Comment: Again, you need to have a solid understanding of the `main` and the `renderer` processes.  WHICH console are you looking at?

Comment: I looked at the devtool's console. i think i did something wrong for the console.log to not show up. it shows up now. but still there is a lack of articles on actually sending message from the main process to the renderer process. i have been looking at articles for quite a while, and i think i got it to work.